# PHPmailer received from

Tags: php, phpmailer, spam-prevention

A recruitment application we have built uses mail() to send notifications and so on to clients and their candidates. We have had a few requests from clients who want to be able to bulk email candidates job profiles etc and so on but, as the mail comes from our servers, we don't want to use mail() as the from address, reply to and so on is from our server so if it was abused it would be our server which was blacklisted.

As a result, we looked at using phpmailer - functionally it works great and uses the SMTP details but in the headers it still shows our server name and IP address. If someone was to use the system maliciously (sending bulk emails to candidates who have request their details be removed, for example) I assume our server would still get blacklisted - is this the case?

The majority of the headers show my server info and the SMTP server name is actually only shown once so what does anti-spam software actually look at in the headers to determine if it is good or bad?

```
Return-path: <from-address-in-phpmailer>
Envelope-to: to-address-in-phpmailer
Delivery-date: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 11:20:22 +0000
Received: from MYSERVERNAME ([myserveripaddress]:60045 helo=www.mydomain.com)
    by from-address-server-name with esmtpa (Exim 4.80)
    (envelope-from <from-address-in-phpmailer>)
    id 1Tj6py-00033k-1H
    for to-address-in-phpmailer; Thu, 13 Dec 2012 11:20:22 +0000
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 11:20:22 +0000
To: Recipient <to-address-in-phpmailer>
From: Sender <from-address-in-phpmailer>
Reply-to: Sender <from-address-in-phpmailer>
Subject: PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication
Message-ID: <c081a17b2526d1268a1e6cd33f212f31@MYSERVERNAME>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_c081a17b2526d1268a1e6cd33f212f31"
X-Brightmail-Tracker: AAAAAA==
X-Brightmail-Tracker: AAAAAA==
```

Answer (score 1):

> I assume our server would still get blacklisted - is this the case?

Yes, because the email would be coming from your server.

The From: address is non-authoriative (and easily spoofed as we know).

Anti-Spam software looks at (amongst other things) the sending server's IP.  It's normally IP addresses that are blacklisted (for per server blacklists).

Comment: Thought as much, is there any way of allowing clients to send mail where their potential abuse would not impact our servers reputation?

Comment: Only way is if they used their own SMTP server. PHPMailer allows you to send via another SMTP server. So you would have to allow them to enter in their server IP / Host name, username, password so that you could connect and send though their server.